# Infragistics igGrid Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui

Hello i have an error in my Javascript with Infragistics Grid.

When i put `$("#grid").igGrid` in `$.getJSON` i have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getHU() {
        var hu = document.getElementById("IP").value;
        var param = location.search.split('q=')[1]
        var url = '/Home/ListContactJson/?q=' + hu;
        getDos(url);  
    }

    function getDos(url) {
        $.getJSON(url, function (q) {
        // Grid
            $("#grid").igGrid({
                width: "100%",
                dataSource: q,
                autoGenerateColumns: false,
                columns: [{
                    key: "LASTNAME",
                    headerText: "LASTNAME",
                    width: "33.33%"
                }],
                features: [{
                    name: "Sorting",
                    columnSettings: [{
                        columnKey: "LASTNAME",
                        currentSortDirection: "descending"
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you have the JS reference to the library included in the page?

Comment: Yes i import     infragistics.core.js and infragistics.lob.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different version of the IgniteUI or jQuery and see the result. This might help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remove some elements in my code, it works but without this code :

> $( ".link" ).click(function() {});

I want to call this code, when i click on my button .link, but it doesn't work, i have the same error than the first post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".link").click(function() {
           var hu = document.getElementById("IP").value;
           var param = location.search.split('q=')[1]
           var url = '/Home/ListContactJson/?q=jean';

            $.getJSON(url, function (q) {
                // Grid

              $("#grid").igGrid({
                    width: "100%",
                    dataSource: q,
                    autoGenerateColumns: false,
                    columns: [{
                        key: "LASTNAME",
                        headerText: "LASTNAME",
                        width: "33.33%"
                    }],
                    features: [{
                        name: "Sorting",
                        columnSettings: [{
                            columnKey: "LASTNAME",
                            currentSortDirection: "descending"
                        }]
                    }]
                });
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with this info because it's a part of it :)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that `location` belongs to the global object `window` and once inside the `click` event handler the context of the handler is no longer the global context, thus `location` is an undefined local variable. The error is coming from there, not from the `igGrid` code. Change your code to the following and everything should work fine.

```
var param = window.location.search.split('q=')[1];
```